# how to get product details from a upc?

Tags: android, barcode

in my android application i get the UPC code of any product using a barcode reader.
but once i get the upc code how can i get the details programatically.

I searched on internet and one thing i found is "go to upcdatabase site, type the upc number and details will be displayed" but there must be an API to get these details right. can someone help me regarding this thing. thank you.

Ignore the code below:

```
package com.android.barcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BarcodeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                        requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (scanResult != null) {
                    String upc = scanResult.getContents();

                    // put whatever you want to do with the code here
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(upc);
                    setContentView(tv);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue?I am also new to android and finding the solution same.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the webstie UPC Database theres a API information page located here: [UPC API Information](http://www.upcdatabase.org/api.php)